# Can I use Logistic Regression on multinomial categories?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multinomial-distribution

Im trying to run a program to conduct machine learning on.

I want to use Logistic Regression, but the problem is the values imputed run as follows -

1 - Yes
2 - No
3 - Maybe
9 - Unavailable

I dont think I could run

Comment: You can use logistic regression for multinomial classification.Have a look at softmax regression or one vs all classification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the values for the dependent variable, you can use multinomial logistic regression.  However, usually, one would delete the cases where the DV is missing - unless it being missing is meaningful.

If you do decide to delete the missing, then it *might* make sense to use ordinal logistic with recoding so that 1 = yes, 2 = maybe, 3 = no.

If this is an independent variable, please specify.

Also, if you give context, it would help.  My blog post ["How to ask a statistics question"](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you formulate this question in a better way